# Sensitivity of correlation swaps to stochastic volatility

Tags: options, swaps, correlation

Are correlation swaps sensitive to stochastic volatility? Can you please justify from a theoretical point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you ask if there is a difference if you model them via stochastic vol as opposed to local vol for example? If so, yes. The effect is called [decorrelation](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3228065). Since  SV has vols fluctuate as opposed to deterministic, you get more variation in the price of the underlyings. Hence, your effective realized correlation is smaller in SV.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, AKdemy. The argument sounds good. But will it be a significant change as compared to the local vol is a valid question. Because stochastic vol may not necessarily increase the randomness of the underlying stock and decorrelate. We may simply need a very high value of vol for the decorrelation effect, not necessarily a stoch vol.

Comment: No matter your level of vol, LV will never decorrelate as vol is deterministic. [ellie_cat](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/63561/54838) added a good comment about validity of LV. I also mentioned [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/63564/54838) that LV is often actually close to market quotes.